# Can I assign a new Map object to an observable in mobx?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have an instance of some class, say FooClass, which has a property, myMap. Recently, I was informed by my server that the Map has some new content. Can I assign a new Map to myMap, or is that not ok for mobx?

If it is not ok, I guess I need to reconcile the two maps. Is there a utiliy function in mobx for doing that?

```
class FooClass {
    constructor() { makeObservable(this); }
    @observable myMap = new Map();
}

let foo = new FooClass();

runInAction(() => foo.myMap.set("foo", "123"));

runInAction(() => foo.myMap = new Map()); // <- Is this ok or am I being naughty?
```

P.S. I'm using babel, so the decorators will be transformed and it does not pose a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might some extra re-renders in some corner cases but it is totally fine to assign new `Map` if you need or if it is much easier than merge them. It is basically the same as reassigning array or object.